# Bootstrap Switch throws Error while applying any function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap switch http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

When I try to apply any function using following code

```
$('#switch5').bootstrapSwitch('setSizeClass', 'switch-mini');
```

it gives me this error over and over again.

```
Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

am I missing something?

Comment: What are your Bootstrap Switch / Bootstrap versions?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3.1

Comment: What's your jQuery version?

Comment: 1.10 is the jQuery version.